# PLS HELP ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'r2' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'r2'

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Need to Fix this errror, I dont know what to do my syntax is not wrong but if i run it displays the error

my app-routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'recipes',
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      loadChildren:
      './recipes/recipes.module#RecipesPageModule'
    },
    {
      path: ':recipeId',
      loadChildren:
      './recipes/recipe-detail/recipe-detail.module#RecipeDetailPageModule'
    }
  ]},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

my recipe-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from './recipe.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RecipesService {

  private recipes: Recipe[] = [
    {
      id: 'r1',
      title: 'Smoked Fish',
// tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
      imageUrl: '../assets/img/sugba.jpg',
      ingredients: ['Fish', 'Salt', 'Lemon Grass']
    },
    {
      id: 'r2',
      title: 'Raw Fish',
// tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
      imageUrl: '../assets/img/rawfish.jpg',
      ingredients: ['Fish', 'Salt', 'Onion']
    },
  ];

  constructor() { }
  getAllRecipes(){
    return [...this.recipes];
  }
  getRecipe(recipeId: string){
    return {...this.recipes.find(recipe => {
      return recipe.id === recipeId;
    })};
  }
}
```

my recipes.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title color="primary">recipes</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let recipe of recipes" [routerLink]="['/', recipe.id]">
    <ion-avatar>
      <ion-img [src] = "recipe.imageUrl">

      </ion-img>
    </ion-avatar>
    <ion-label>
      {{recipe.title}}
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'r2'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'r2'

Comment: I think you need: `[routerLink]="['recipes/', recipe.id]"` which actually match the Route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let recipe of recipes" [routerLink]="['/', recipe.id]">
```

`[routerLink]="['/', recipe.id]"` means you're redirecting to the root route. But your expected route is a child of the route.

Use this instead :

```
[routerLink]="recipe.id"
```